# Improve performance of finding graph diameter in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, graph, functional-programming

I'm solving the following [problem](http://judge.telerikacademy.com/problem/03diameter), which in essence is "find the diameter of a connected undirected weighted graph", in Haskell. Now, the solution below produces correct answers, but exceeds the time limit on 9/27 of the tests. I'm far from a Haskell prodigy, can you guys give me a clue whether and how I can improve the performance of my solution without using the builtin `Data.Graph` module? I tried using accumulator parameters, strict pairs and strict evaluation in some places, but either I used them incorrectly or the performance issue is elsewhere. Thanks in advance!

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

buildGraph :: [Int] -> Map.Map Int [(Int, Int)] -> Map.Map Int [(Int, Int)]
buildGraph [] acc                  = acc
buildGraph (from:to:dist:rest) acc = let withTo = Map.insertWith (++) from [(to, dist)] acc
                                        withFromTo = Map.insertWith (++) to [(from, dist)] withTo
                                        in buildGraph rest $ withFromTo

data Queue a = Queue {
                ingoing :: [a]
                , outgoing :: [a]
            } deriving Show

toQueue xs = Queue [] xs
enqMany xs (Queue is os) = (Queue (reverse xs ++ is) os)
deq (Queue is []) = deq (Queue [] $ reverse is)
deq (Queue is (o:os)) = (o, Queue is os)

extract :: (Ord a) => a -> Map.Map a [b] -> [b]
extract k m = case Map.lookup k m of
                    Just value -> value
                    Nothing    -> error "sdfsd" -- should never happen

bfs node graph = bfs' Set.empty (toQueue [(node, 0)]) []
    where
        bfs' :: Set.Set Int -> Queue (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]
        bfs' visited (Queue [] []) acc = acc
        bfs' visited que acc = let ((n, dist), rest) = deq que
                                    in if Set.member n visited
                                            then bfs' visited rest acc
                                            else let children = map (\(i, d) -> (i, d + dist)) $ extract n graph
                                                    newNodes = enqMany children rest
                                                    in bfs' (Set.insert n visited) newNodes ((n, dist):acc)

findMostDistant xs = maximumBy (comparing snd) xs

solve input = answer
    where
        -- the first number is the number of edges and is not necessary
        (_:triples) = map read $ words input
        graph = buildGraph triples Map.empty
        -- pick arbitary node, find the farther node from it using bfs
        (mostDistant, _) = findMostDistant $ bfs (head triples) graph
        -- find the farthest node from the previously farthest node, counting the distance on the way
        (_, answer) = findMostDistant $ bfs mostDistant graph

tests = [
            "11 2 7 2 1 7 6 5 1 8 2 8 6 8 6 9 10 5 5 9 1 9 0 10 15 3 1 21 6 4 3" -- 54
            , "5 3 4 3 0 3 4 0 2 6 1 4 9" -- 22
            , "16 2 3 92 5 2 10 14 3 42 2 4 26 14 12 50 4 6 93 9 6 24 15 14 9 0 2 95 8 0 90 0 13 60 9 10 59 1 0 66 11 12 7 7 10 35" -- 428
        ]

runZeroTests = mapM_ print $ map solve tests

main = do
    answer <- solve <$> getContents
    print answer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from @Davislor with doing IO using `ByteString` and a few other things I managed to get 100 points on the problem. In the end, what I did to optimize it was:

1. Using `ByteString` IO as @Davislor suggested
2. Since I knew integers in the input were valid, I wrote my own `parseInt` function that does not perform unnecessary checks.
3. Instead of lazy `Map`, I used `Array` to create an adjacency list. I do not know what the asymptotic complexity of constructing an `Array` using `accumArray` is (I believe it should be `O(n)`), but lookup in the array should be `O(1)`, instead of the `O(log n)` for the `Map`.

Here is the final solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Data.ByteString.Builder
(Builder, char7, intDec, toLazyByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B8
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.Char (ord)
import Data.ByteString (getLine)
import Data.Array (Array, array, accumArray, (!), (//))

buildAdjList :: Int -> [Int] -> Array Int [(Int, Int)]
buildAdjList n xs = accumArray (flip (:)) [] (0, n) $ triples xs []
    where
        triples [] res = res
        triples (x:y:dist:rest) res = let edgeXY = (x, (y, dist))
                                        edgeYX = (y, (x, dist))
                                        in triples rest (edgeXY:edgeYX:res)

data Queue a = Queue {
                ingoing :: [a]
                , outgoing :: [a]
            } deriving Show

enqMany xs (Queue is os) = Queue (reverse xs ++ is) os
deq (Queue [] []) = error "gosho"
deq (Queue is []) = deq (Queue [] $ reverse is)
deq (Queue is (o:os)) = (o, Queue is os)

bfs !node adjList = let start = (node, 0) in bfs' Set.empty (Queue [] [start]) start
    where
        bfs' :: Set.Set Int -> Queue (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
        bfs' visited (Queue [] []) !ans = ans
        bfs' visited que !ans = let (curr@(n, dist), rest) = deq que
                                    in if Set.member n visited
                                            then bfs' visited rest ans
                                            else let children = map (\(i, d) -> (i, d + dist)) $ adjList ! n
                                                    newNodes = enqMany children rest
                                                    in bfs' (Set.insert n visited) newNodes (longerEdge curr ans)

longerEdge :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
longerEdge a b = if (snd a) < (snd b) then b else a

parseInt :: B8.ByteString -> Int
parseInt str = parseInt' str 0 where
    parseInt' str !acc
        | B8.null str  = acc
        | otherwise = parseInt' (B8.tail str) $ ((ord $ B8.head str) - 48 + acc * 10)

parseIntList :: B8.ByteString -> [Int]
parseIntList = map parseInt . B8.words

solve :: [Int] -> Int
solve (n:triples) = answer
    where
        graph = buildAdjList n triples
        -- pick arbitary node, find the farther node from it using bfs
        (mostDistant, _) = bfs (head triples) graph
        -- find the farthest node from the previously farthest node, counting the distance on the way
        (_, answer) = bfs mostDistant graph

main :: IO ()
main = B8.interact ( toLazyByteString . intDec . solve . parseIntList )

-- debug code below
tests = [
            "11 2 7 2 1 7 6 5 1 8 2 8 6 8 6 9 10 5 5 9 1 9 0 10 15 3 1 21 6 4 3" -- 54
            , "5 3 4 3 0 3 4 0 2 6 1 4 9" -- 22
            , "16 2 3 92 5 2 10 14 3 42 2 4 26 14 12 50 4 6 93 9 6 24 15 14 9 0 2 95 8 0 90 0 13 60 9 10 59 1 0 66 11 12 7 7 10 35" -- 428
        ]

runZeroTests = B8.putStr
    . toLazyByteString
    . foldMap format
    . map (solve . parseIntList)
    $ tests

format :: Int -> Builder
format n = intDec n <> eol
    where eol = char7 '\n'
```

There could still be room for improvement, the `Set` for visited nodes could be changed to a bit array, `Int32` can be used instead of `Int`, `BangPatterns` could be applied, although I feel like I can't really make sense of the execution order of Haskell programs.

Comment: As for evaluation order: there’s a formal answer that involves compiling Haskell programs to lambda expressions, but in practice there are only two times I’ve found I cared. One was when I’m relying on lazy evaluation to avoid infinite recursion, so I need to put the expression that might never terminate to the right of the one that will. The other is when I’m optimizing for speed or memory by explicitly forcing strict evaluation, and then I override it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`deq (Queue [] [])` causes an infinite loop, I think.

Comment: Should probably get a pattern guard and `error` clause.

Answer (score 1):

When I’ve solved contest problems in Haskell, typically the biggest performance hog has been the slow I/O library, which operates on lazy linear linked lists of wide characters.  The first thing I always do for a programming contest is replace that with fast I/O,

Here’s a version that makes minimal changes to the program logic and just replaces the I/O with `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8`, implemented with a lazily-evaluated list of strict byte arrays, and `Data.ByteString.Builder`, which builds a function to fill an output buffer.  It should be useful to calculate the speed-up from fast I/O alone.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-} -- Added

import Data.ByteString.Builder
  (Builder, char7, intDec, toLazyByteString) -- Added
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B8 -- Added
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust) -- Added
import Data.Monoid ((<>)) -- Added
import Data.Ord (comparing)

buildGraph :: [Int] -> Map.Map Int [(Int, Int)] -> Map.Map Int [(Int, Int)]
buildGraph [] acc                  = acc
buildGraph (from:to:dist:rest) acc = let withTo = Map.insertWith (++) from [(to, dist)] acc
                                         withFromTo = Map.insertWith (++) to [(from, dist)] withTo
                                        in buildGraph rest $ withFromTo

data Queue a = Queue {
                ingoing :: [a]
                , outgoing :: [a]
            } deriving Show

toQueue xs = Queue [] xs
enqMany xs (Queue is os) = (Queue (reverse xs ++ is) os)
deq (Queue is []) = deq (Queue [] $ reverse is)
deq (Queue is (o:os)) = (o, Queue is os)

extract :: (Ord a) => a -> Map.Map a [b] -> [b]
extract k m = case Map.lookup k m of
                    Just value -> value
                    Nothing    -> error "sdfsd" -- should never happen

bfs node graph = bfs' Set.empty (toQueue [(node, 0)]) []
    where
        bfs' :: Set.Set Int -> Queue (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]
        bfs' visited (Queue [] []) acc = acc
        bfs' visited que acc = let ((n, dist), rest) = deq que
                                    in if Set.member n visited
                                            then bfs' visited rest acc
                                            else let children = map (\(i, d) -> (i, d + dist)) $ extract n graph
                                                     newNodes = enqMany children rest
                                                    in bfs' (Set.insert n visited) newNodes ((n, dist):acc)

findMostDistant xs = maximumBy (comparing snd) xs

solve triples = answer -- Changed (by deleting one line)
    where
        graph = buildGraph triples Map.empty
        -- pick arbitary node, find the farther node from it using bfs
        (mostDistant, _) = findMostDistant $ bfs (head triples) graph
        -- find the farthest node from the previously farthest node, counting the distance on the way
        (_, answer) = findMostDistant $ bfs mostDistant graph

tests = [ -- Unchanged, but now interpreted as OverloadedStrings
            "11 2 7 2 1 7 6 5 1 8 2 8 6 8 6 9 10 5 5 9 1 9 0 10 15 3 1 21 6 4 3" -- 54
            , "5 3 4 3 0 3 4 0 2 6 1 4 9" -- 22
            , "16 2 3 92 5 2 10 14 3 42 2 4 26 14 12 50 4 6 93 9 6 24 15 14 9 0 2 95 8 0 90 0 13 60 9 10 59 1 0 66 11 12 7 7 10 35" -- 428
        ]

runZeroTests = B8.putStr -- Changed
  . toLazyByteString
  . foldMap format
  . map (solve . parse)
  $ tests

main :: IO () -- Changed
main = B8.interact ( toLazyByteString . format . solve . parse )

parse :: B8.ByteString -> [Int] -- Added
-- the first number is the number of edges and is not necessary
parse = map (fst . fromJust . B8.readInt) . tail . B8.words

format :: Int -> Builder -- Added
format n = intDec n <> eol where
  eol = char7 '\n'
```

Comment: Looks reasonable, will try it out tomorrow :)

Comment: Oh, and the contest judge might also accept `{#- OPTIONS_GHC -O3 -fllvm -#}` for some more speedup, or it might not. Let me know how much difference that makes.

Comment: The next step would be to make sure you’re using the right algorithm and data structures before micro-optimizing stuff like strictness, eagerness, and eliminating intermediate lists. Haven’t analyzed that in any detail yet.

Comment: Your changes resulted in a considerable performance boost - I'm still getting time limits, but on fewer tests.

Comment: In my experience, the fist thing you should always do in any programming-contest problem for Haskell is plug in some fast I/O boilerplate. It will make any solution that uses the `Prelude` run in a fraction of the time. Then look at your algorithm and, in particular, your data structures. You probably want to solve this one yourself, but a look at the problem statement says the graph is actually a *tree*, which means you can find the root of the tree and the two longest branches in linear time.

Comment: Well, the problem description states that it's a tree like structure, but a close look at the provided input actually reveals that a root cannot be determined based on the input. Consider one of the sample tests `(3 4) (0 3) (0 2) (1 4)` 

The structure described by the edges listed above cannot be a rooted tree because if we assume the edges are directed, than either `4` or `0` has more than one parent.

Coming to think about it, this might be a directed graph. I'll try treating the graph as directed and see where this goes :)

Comment: `{#- OPTIONS_GHC -O3 -fllvm -#}` Didn't help much. The `-fllvm` flag caused compile error on my machina as well as on the judge system.

Comment: Got to be undirected, or in the second example, the path 0->10->5->1->7->2->8->6->4 fails at the 7->2 step.  But all the examples are connected and acyclic.